# sql create table with foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

In my database I need to create a table which has two foreign keys, I am unable to figure out  the source of error  although I tried .Any body help me in solving this problem. 
The mysql command I gave to create the table

```
create table book_vegetable(
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  producer_offer_id int NOT NULL,
  consumer_id int NOT NULL,
  booked_qty varchar,
  PRIMARY KEY(id),
  FOREIGN KEY(producer_offer_id) 
    REFERENCES producer_offer(id),
  FOREIGN KEY(consumer_id) REFERENCES user(id)
);
```

The error I am getting

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'PRIMARY KEY(id),FOREIGN KEY(producer_offer_id) REFERENCES
>   producer_offer(id),FOR' at line 1

Comment: add a size to the varchar column, eg. varchar(255)

Comment: it says "Can't create table 'affm1.book_vegetable' (errno: 150)" after i specified the length of varchar

Comment: do `producer_offer` and `user` tables have a correctly defined primary key named `id` ?

Comment: post the output of `show create table book_vegetable;` and `show create table user;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first problem was caused by a missing length specification on the  booked_qty varchar column.

The usual suspects for error 150:

- mismatch in primary vs. foreign key type (for example int - bigint). make sure they match exactly
- different table engines (for example if you try to reference a MyIsam table in a InnoDB table)

Comment: Also signed - unsigned.

Comment: ya  There was a problem with the  length and  type "unsigned" fixed by

Answer (score 1):

This works in MySQL, just tested (note that producer offer and user are just a mock tables).

```
create table producer_offer (id int(10) not null auto_increment, primary key(id));
create table user (id int(10) not null auto_increment, primary key(id));

create table book_vegetable (
    id int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    producer_offer_id int(10) NOT NULL,
    consumer_id int(10) NOT NULL,
    booked_qty varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(producer_offer_id) REFERENCES producer_offer(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(consumer_id) REFERENCES user(id)
);
```